# Answer for the $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{x^2}{1-\cos x}$?

Tags: limits-without-lhopital

So I know that you can multiply by the conjugate and get the correct answer which is 2. However I wanted to know why this method gave me the wrong answer. [how I tried to solve it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m4L5r.jpg)

Comment: $0^{-1}$ is not defined.

Comment: And also $0\times\infty$  is indeterminate. That means you need to apply a good method of finding limit.

Comment: oooohhhh completely forgot that (0)^-1 is 1/0 which is undefined. thank you very much

Comment: Maybe you could use MathJax to type your question. https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 1):

You could do this:
\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{x^2}{1-\cos(x)}&=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{x^2(1+\cos(x))}{1-\cos^2(x)}\\
&=\lim_{x\to0}(1+\cos(x))\frac{x^2}{\sin^2(x)}\\
&=2\lim_{x\to0}\frac{x^2}{\sin^2(x)}
\end{align}

The right hand side is $(\mathrm{sinc}(x))^{-2}$, which is [well known](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sinc_function) to be $1$ for $x\to0$.

Comment: We can also write the function as $\frac{x^2}{2\sin^2(x/2)}=\frac{2}{\operatorname{sinc}^2(x/2)}$.

Answer (score 0):

$0\times 0^{-1}=0 \times \frac{1}{0}$ (there's an indeterminate form)

It may solve also without L`Hopital Rule.

$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{x^2}{1-\cos x}=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{x^2}{1-(1-2\sin^2 \frac{x}{2})}$

$=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{x^2}{2\sin^2 \frac{x}{2}}$

$=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{4\times (\frac{x}{2})^2}{2\sin^2 \frac{x}{2}}$

$=2\times \lim_{x\rightarrow 0}(\frac{\frac{x}{2}}{\sin \frac{x}{2}})^2$

$=2\times 1=2$